# Calculate area of polygon in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I cannot calculate the area of a polygon in D3 using the function `path.area()`

I have tried feeding it a list of coordinates as follows:

```
var d = [
      [-1, 415.44],
      [146.93, 304.47],
      [195.45, 152.13],
      [-1, 134.64]
    ]

path.area(d)
```

I have also tried to feed it (what I think is) a TopoJSON object, as follows:

```
path.area({        
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon", 
            "coordinates": d},            
        });
```

The first attempt gives you value `0`. The second gives you `'NaN'`. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong? As an FYI, I need to calculate the area of a polygon that I reference as follows:

```
d3.select("#IDofpolygon");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [d3.polygonArea](https://github.com/d3/d3-polygon/blob/master/README.md#polygonArea), which:

> Returns the signed area of the specified polygon. If the vertices of the polygon are in counterclockwise order (assuming a coordinate system where the origin ⟨0,0⟩ is in the top-left corner), the returned area is positive; otherwise it is negative, or zero.

Here is the demo:

```js
var d = [
  [-1, 415.44],
  [146.93, 304.47],
  [195.45, 152.13],
  [-1, 134.64]
];

var area = d3.polygonArea(d);

console.log(area)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see topojson, I go straight to geoPaths, erroneously - this is a much more likely (and better) answer than mine.

Comment: You fell victim of the *"XY problem"*! Undelete your answer, OP may like it better.

Comment: Gerardo, grateful for your answer, boss. This is very simple and works perfectly.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado while it is relevant to the assembly of geojson in the question, you are right on with the xy problem, it doesn't add anything, and your answer is more than sufficient, mine will only provide clutter.